# Ajax disables jQuery click event in WordPress Search & Filter Pro

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, onclick

**CONTEXT**

I'm using a a Wordpress plugin (Search & Filter Pro) to filter posts by category and load results via Ajax. Since I have several categories-of-categories (e.g. authors, topics, etc.), I added the code below to make the each super-category behave as an accordion:

```
 jQuery(function($) {
   $('li h4').on("click", function(){
     console.log('hello!')

     //Expand or collapse this panel
     $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');

   });
 });
```

**PROBLEM**

On initial load, this works perfectly, as intended. However, as soon as I click a category and the filtered results show up in the content box, the accordion no longer works and even my `console.log` fails. None of the classes change after the results have loaded.

**QUESTION**

Is there any way the Ajax loading could be disabling the ability to use jQuery to target elements as in the code above?

Comment: probably because you replace the elements and you did not rebind the events to the new ones.

Comment: @epascarello - spot on, I had to use ``` $('li').on("click", 'h4', function(){}``` instead. Thanks for your help!